# ImportError only when running a script from windows using WIN-R

Tags: python, importerror

I have a simple script which I'm trying to run from windows:

Script:

```
#! python3
# pw.py - An insecure password locker program

import sys
import pyperclip

PASSWORDS = {"email": "DHUSADIUSAHDDSAJO",
             "blog": "fdsifjdsfjisdojfios",
             "luggage": "fdsjifidsfhjifhui"}

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("Usage: python pw.py[account] - copy account password")
    sys.exit()

account = sys.argv[1] # first command line arg is account name

if account in PASSWORDS:
    pyperclip.copy(PASSWORDS[account])
    print("The password for your {} account has been sent to the computer \
clipboard.".format(account))
else:
    print("There is no account named {}.".format(account))
```

Batch file:

```
@py.exe C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\2016Coding\AutomateBoring\pw.py
@pause
```

I can run this script through Idle and the command line without issue. But through windows I receive:

```
<absolute filepath>, line 5, in <module>
    import pyperclip
ImportError: No module named 'pyperclip'
```

I'm using python 3.1.1 and that module was initially installed into its default python27/lib/site-packages. After figuring that out I used `pip-install --target` to add it the the same folder of 'python31'. The batch and .py files are in the same folder and the folder location is in ev Path.